# Open multiple views in multiple browser tabs in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular page with header, sidebar and a view with different routes (Parent page). There is a requirement to open multiple tabs with the same header and sidebar but different view (Child page). Also, the changes in the child view (second tab) need to be propagated to the parent tab. window.open opens a new tab but the current view is also getting updated. Is there any way this could be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes . Use loca storage with the angular ngStorage module.

http://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

I authored a small module  to accomplish this for session storage:

https://github.com/yaacovCR/angular-stored-object

inspired by ngStorage and http://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/